# Как передвинуть конец бинарного файла в си?

Tags: c, файлы

Как передвинуть конец бинарного файла в си?

Comment: Шта сделать... `fseek`?

Comment: Откуда куда зачем передвинуть? Ничего не понятно

Comment: [man truncate](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/truncate.2.html)

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно расшифровал, что нужно...

```
FILE * f = ...
fseek(f,0,SEEK_END);
```

https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fseek

Comment: `man truncate(2)` очевидно более вероятный ответ.

Comment: @0andriy, с чего вы решили. что он работает под `Linux` ? В винде нет этой фичи

Comment: @And, с чего вы взяли, что я говорю про Linux? Но для тех, кто идёт своим путём есть тоже решения: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/873454/how-to-truncate-a-file-in-c

Comment: @0andriy, с того, что в винде нет этого, о чем вы написали выше про `truncate`.

Comment: @And, а причём тут вообще конктретная ОС? Вы вопрос читали?

Comment: @0andriy, зачастую так и происходит, что пользователи на `windows`, а если нет, то в метке появляется или в вопросе `Linux` или их семейства.